What is this turn-based, hex-based iOS strategy game? Light-hearted fantasy RTS about wizards and towers
I played a really great turn-based strategy game on iOS several years ago (mid-noughties) and i'm trying to find it again. I can't even see it in my list of previously-downloaded apps (which does show games which are no longer available on the app store), although it might be there and i'm just not spotting it for some reason (i have downloaded a lot of games).
It was a hex-based turn-based strategy game where you are a clumsy, absent-minded wizard. It had a tongue-in-cheek vibe, and a cartoonish art style. The game revolved around trying to capture towers, which acted like bases I think.
I have a feeling there was a sequel but i'm not sure.
Does anyone know what i'm talking about?
